# How to call a dictionary as a parameter for stored procedure

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to use the dictionary in a parameter to call a stored procedure to update a table that uses a value in the Dict as a foreign key.

Dict data (ID is the foreign key) ex:
server1, ID1
server5, ID2

ID is the foreign key on the table i am trying to update and needs to be the parameter when calling the stored procedure. It appears that when i pass in the dictionary as a parameter it is pulling server1 instead of ID1 and causing a key error.

```
with open('DBstatus.csv') as dbcsvfile:
    dbstatus = csv.DictReader(dbcsvfile)
    for row in dbstatus:

#Create parameters for stored procedure
        guardpointparams = (row['FS Agent Registration Status'], row['FS Agent Version'], row['Guard Path'], serverdict[row['Host Name']], policydict[row['Policy Name']], 0)
        #call stored procedure
        updateguardpointstable = cursor.callproc('update_guardpoints', guardpointparams)

#i created the dictionary from a different script while updating the 
"servers" table where the DB is creating the returnvalue (ID) from the 
stored procedure see sample below:

serverdict[row['Host Name']] = returnvalue[3]
```

Traceback: guardpointparams = (row['FS Agent Registration Status'], row['FS Agent Version'], row['Guard Path'], serverdict[row['Host Name']], policydict[row['Policy Name']], 0)
KeyError: 'server1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row['Host Name']` appears to be `server1`. The dictionary `serverdict` does not have a key named `server1`

Comment: It might be wise to take a defensive stance on whether the `serverdict` key existed before using it, or if there's a sensible default try `serverdict.get(row['Host Name'], sensible_default)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either your `serverdict` or your `policydict` is not defined. At least you don't provide the definition in your example. Further, the traceback tells you that one of these don't have the key you are looking for.